# How can I get the "Group and Tab Windows" plugin in compiz on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, compiz, plugins

A while ago I remember using the compiz plugin "Group and Tab Windows". Now I would like to use it again, but I have found out that it is part of the compiz-plugins-extra, which is just an empty transition package. Is there another way of installing this plugin?

Comment: While the question was on-topic in December 31, 2014, Ubuntu 14.04 has reached its end of life now, and thus this question is off-topic. If you are using a supported version of Ubuntu, you may want to update the question and the tag.